# How to find the modules of a big number with a big powe ??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modules, discrete-optimization

How to find the modulus of a big number with a big power?

Such as $2222^{5555}$  or $5555^{2222}$ (mod 7)?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$2222\equiv 3 \mod 7$$ and $$3^6\equiv 1 \mod 7$$, $$5555 \equiv 4\mod 7$$ and $$4^3\equiv 1 \mod 7$$

Answer (score 1):

**5551** is divisible by **7**

So, $$5555  \equiv  4 (mod 7)  $$
raise both sides to power 3: $$5555^3 \equiv 4^3 (mod 7)$$
But, $$4^3 \equiv 1(mod 7)$$
It gives $$5555^3 \equiv 1(mod 7)$$
now, since **2222** **is not** divisible by **3**, but **2220** **is**, **2220=740 $\cdot$3**,
raise both sides to **740** $$(5555^3)^{740}=1^{740} (mod 7)$$ i.e. $$5555^{2220}=1 (mod 7)$$
Also, $$5555^2 \equiv 2(mod 7)$$ So, multiplying both, you get $$5555^{2222}=2(mod 7)$$
You can proceed similarly for $$2222^{5555} (mod 7)$$